# How many Ethers has the Ethereum Switzerland GmbH?

Tags: shares

As I understand, the EthSuisse founded Ethereum in 2014. How many Ether do they have mined for themselves and how many are in the community?

Answer (score 2):

For those who haven't seen it, the PDF of the Terms and Conditions of the Ethereum Genesis Sale can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/www/blob/master-postsale/src/extras/pdfs/TermsAndConditionsOfTheEthereumGenesisSale.pdf). (See the parent [`pdf`](https://github.com/ethereum/www/tree/master-postsale/src/extras/pdfs) directory for more gems.)

On page 8 of the document:

> In addition to the Genesis Sale Quantity of ETH, the pre-mining
>   process will create and place a second pool of ETH in the Genesis
>   Block. This second pool of ETH will be directly allocated to early
>   contributors who have worked to develop the ideas, implementations,
>   and supporting structures of the Ethereum project up to the time of
>   the Genesis Sale. The size of this pool will be 9.9% of Genesis Sale
>   Quantity of ETH.

I believe the initial sale raised the equivalent of $18 million (i.e. the Genesis Sale Quantity), but I can't immediately find a source, so I'm happy to be corrected.

At the time of the sale, EthSuisse was a GmbH (Gesellschaft mit beschränkter Haftung) - i.e. a company with legal liability, and therefore a legal entity governed by the terms and conditions, which made it more difficult to run off with the money. The company was liquidated, ***as per plan***, and as laid out in the above document, after the Genesis block was created.

I'm unsure how to determine how much the Ethereum Foundation currently have, and how this relates to the individuals who were rewarded as members of EthSuisse. Someone closer to the Foundation might know more. (Note: It's been suggested that [this](https://etherscan.io/address/0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae) is their account, though I don't know if this has been formally confirmed.)

Comment: That would be 353,618.4 Ether